# What's wrong with $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Set $$y=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i     $$
Multiply both side by $x$, then we have
$$yx=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i+1}$$
Use the first one to minus the second one, we have
$$y(1-x)=1$$
Then we have
$$y=\frac{1}{1-x}$$,
which means that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

But obviously only when $|{x}|<1$ the equation holds.

So what's wrong with the deduction process above? I opaquely heard about that it's related to the convergence domain, but I hardly get the hang of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issues is (as others have mentioned) when you subtract the two series. The rules for adding or subtracting series say that you can only do this when you have *convergent* series. So if $\lvert x\lvert \geq 1$ then the series that you have set to be $y$ is not convergent. Hence you don't know that you can subtract the two series in that case.

The rule is that: If the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent with sum $a$ and $\sum b_n$ is convergent with sum $b$, then the series $\sum a_n + b_n$ is convergent with sum $a + b$.

Note again the requirement that you have to start with two series that you *know* are convergent.

But since you are trying to prove the formula, you don't a priori know when the series converges even for $\lvert x\lvert < 1$.

That is why you have you have to start with finite sums as is done in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Comment: A small TeXnical tip: if you use `\lvert`, then you should also use `\rvert`. Thus, to denote the absolute value of `x`, the best usage is `\lvert x \rvert`. Note that `|x|` also works (but `|\sin x|` has spacing issues that `\lvert \sin x \rvert` does not have).

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Thanks for the tip! It actually makes sense now that you say it with the l in lvert being left. I will try to do that from now on.

Answer (score 6):

For $x\geq1$: $$y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^nx^i=\infty,\\
yx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^nx^{i+1}=\infty\Rightarrow\\
y-yx=\infty-\infty=?$$

Answer (score 4):

Really, the problem is the way you operate on the first equality: when you let $y$  equal an infinite sum, $y$ could be possibly infinite, in which case, things like $y - yx$ is of the fishy form $\infty -\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

When you subtract the two equations you might be subtracting infinity from infinity, which is not something you want to do.

Comment: I give the first answer and I get the least number of votes up. SMH

Comment: Answers are voted on not just by when they arrive, but also corresponding to their quality.